# Changing the timestamp of a symlink in macOS with APFS?

Tags: touch, symlink, apfs

According to the man pages of `touch`, in order to change the timestamp on a symbolic link, one can use `touch -h -t MMDDhhmm mylink`.

This does not work on my macOS machine with APFS, the timestamp of the link is unmodified and `touch` follows the link to modify the timestamp of the target.

Is this a known fact about APFS or is there something I haven't understood?

Comment: same here when trying to `touch -r -h`,
to set symlink1's timestamp to another symlink2's timestamp, i get the error:
`touch: symlink2: No such file or directory`.  However, using GNU coreutils' `gtouch` as suggested by @jksoegaard fixes it (installed through homebrew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have found a bug in macOS. The next-to-last major version of the operating system works according to the manual paage, but the latest version does not.

Either the manual page is outdated, or the software has a bug (most likely).

You can send feedback to Apple as a general user here:'

https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html

Or if you are a developer, you can use the Feedback Assistant to file a bug report as described here:

https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

There's currently no newer version of `touch` available from Apple so you cannot as such upgrade your way out of the problem. As you indicate yourself, you can instead use the GNU version of `touch` to get the job done. You can find that in Homebrew by installing `coreutils`.

The GNU version of `touch` works by calling the newer `futimens()`/`utimensat()` functions (in the latter case with the `flag` argument set to `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` to change the timestamp for the link itself).

The Catalina version of `touch` (287.100.2) works by calling the older `lutimes()` function, which explicitly sets the timestamp on the link itself. One of the core differences between the newer and older APIs are that the newer supports timestamps in nanoseconds, whereas the older has a lower resolution.

The `lutimes()` function on Big Sur actually doesn't implement a system call itself, but is actually contained fully in the standards library, using the `setattrlist()` function (which results in a system call) to actually perform the file system modification. `setattrlist()` is highly file system dependent (i.e. how it works on HFS+ file systems would be different from how it works on APFS file systems).

The Big Sur version of `touch` (321.100.11) works by calling the `setattrlist()` function directly, and only if that fails, fall back to `lutimes`. Unfortunately, it seems the programmer forgot about the need to specify that when `-h` is specified, the modification must take place on the link itself.

The actual bug is in line 219 of touch.c, where this line:

```
if (!setattrlist(*argv, &ts_req, &ts_struct, sizeof(ts_struct), 0))
```

should have been:

```
if (!setattrlist(*argv, &ts_req, &ts_struct, sizeof(ts_struct), utimes_f == lutimes ? FSOPT_NOFOLLOW : 0))
```

You could change that in touch.c, recompile it, and get a working binary.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, touch.c has changed from Catalina to Big Sur and a bug has been introduced in `touch` itself (all of this because of the underlying change of infrastructure Intel → AS).

Comment: It has nothing at all to do with a change of “infrastructure” from Intel to AS.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: the default `touch` bundled with macOS cannot change the timestamp, but `touch 8.32` from `GNU coreutils` can...

Interstingly, the 2021 BSD version of touch has the same problem and does not properly handle the `-h` flag.